# IBrokers error message (354 Requested market data is not subscribed.AAPL NASDAQ.NMS/TOP/ALL )

Tags: r, ibrokers

I try to connect TWS(A trading application of Interactive Broker) with a testing script in R.

```
library (IBrokers)
tws <- twsConnect()
aapl.csv <- file("AAPL.csv", open="w")
reqMktData (tws, twsSTK("AAPL"), eventWrapper = eWrapper.MktData.CSV(1), file = aapl.csv)

close(aapl.csv)
close(two)
```

I got error messages. I can retrieve historical data "AAPL" from TWS successfully. Please advise what wrong with the program.

```
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:hfarm 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:jfarm 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:eufarm 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.us 
2 -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm 
2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ilhmds 
2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:fundfarm 
2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ethmds 
2 -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds 
2 1 354 Requested market data is not subscribed.AAPL NASDAQ.NMS/TOP/ALL
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you subscribed?  You probably want the US value bundle.  https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=14193#market-data-fees

Comment: I suspected that there is something wrong without subscribe. However,  It can be shown in the TWS successfully.

Comment: There's free delayed data.  I've read that delayed historical data will be available free some day but it's not for now.  This is also not really a programming question.  If you'd like to test your code, use free data like forex.  I don't know how R handles it, but it's a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The subscriptions on the paper account mirror the subscriptions on the live account.  Here are a few things that could cause that error:

1.You are not paying for the Nasdaq subscription on your live account.

2.Your live account is currently using the subscription and you're trying to request the data on your paper account.  You can't do both.

Comment: This was my problem (years later). Didn't realize I had to subscribe to NASDAQ separately. Thank you!